# Manipulação de horas [HH:MM:SS] - php e mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boa tarde, pessoal.

Preciso manipular campos do tipo time [HH:MM:SS] no próprio PHP.

Eu pego os valores em texto no formulário HTML como no exemplo a seguir:

```html
 <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">P.E: <span data-toggle="tooltip" title=Horário de entrada" class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" name="hora_entrada" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask' : '99:99:99'" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" required="">
                        </div>
                      </div>

  <div class="item form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">S.B.: <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Horário de saída class="required">*</span></label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="text" name="hora_saida" class="form-control" data-inputmask="'mask' : '99:99:99'" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" required="">
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Trago para o script PHP para fazer o cálculo:

```js
$saida = $_POST['saida'];
$entrada = $_POST['entrada'];

//cálculo do hora trabalhada

    $ps = strtotime($saida);
    $pe = strtotime($entrada);

    $horas = ($ps-$pe);
```

Então, caso eu coloque 14:20:00 - 06:00:00, o resultado deveria ser 08:20:00

Mas está vindo: 00:08:00

Alguém sabe como posso fazer esses cálculos?

Obrigada

Comment: Com esses dados que você testa `$horas` está com valor `30000`, ou seja, a diferença em segundos (o que equivale a 8:20). Acho que está correto.

Comment: É que gostaria do valor formatado. Além disso, mostra 00:08:00 no campo da tabela que é do tipo time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu calculo está correto, você só precisa acertar a exibição, que pode ser feita da seguinte forma:

```
$ps = "14:20:00";
$pe = "06:00:00";

$ts1 = strtotime( $ps);
$ts2 = strtotime($pe);
$diff = abs($ts1 - $ts2); // diferença entre os dois tempos

echo gmdate("H:i:s", $diff); // transformação do valor numérico $diff em hora string novamente
```

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigada! Poderia me dizer qual a diferença entre a função date e gmdate (não conhecia essa)?

Comment: Segundo a documentação das duas funções no [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/), a função date() utiliza como timezone a regulada no seu servidor, enquanto gmdate() utiliza timezone de greenwitch.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigada.